# Javascript createImageData throwing DOM exception 9, rgb data not working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

on the Chrome Browser v. 24 when I call the following

> `brush(x,y,w,h)`

the console reports a

> DOM Exception error 9

at this line:

> `var imageData = cvs.createImageData(w,h);`

Also, `setPixel()` should change the `r,g,b,a` values of `imageData.data` as instructed but on my browser it appears transparent. The `brush(...)` creates a transparent, w * h square, which is not what I want it to do.

```
function setPixel(imageData, x, y, r, g, b, a) {
    index = (x + y * imageData.width) * 4;
    imageData.data[index+0] = r;
    imageData.data[index+1] = g;
    imageData.data[index+2] = b;
    imageData.data[index+3] = a;
}

function brush(x, y, w, h) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('maincanvas');
        var cvs = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageData = cvs.createImageData(w,h);
        var r = 0;
        var g = 0;
        var b = 0;

        setPixel(imageData, x, y , r, g, b, 255);
        cvs.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
}
```

My question: is there another reason why the output is transparent besides an exception to `createImageData`?

Comment: @VisioN just the opposite. An alpha of 255 means total opaque.

Answer (score 1):

Try to logging (`console.log()`) your arguments to `createImageData`. This function seems to throw `NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9` when the first argument is `NaN` or `Infinity` (possibly in other cases as well).

Answer (score 0):

A Quote from the following page

" When no styling rules are applied to the canvas it will initially be fully transparent."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Basic_usage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial%2FBasic_usage